# Running PHPUnit from CMD in Windows

Tags: phpunit

I've installed PHPUnit and everything seems to be working fine as when I run `phpunit` from the root php directory `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16` it runs as expected.

However, the problem I am having is running PHPUnit from elsewhere within the command line, so I cannot run any tests because of this. I get the error

```
phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external 
command, operable program or batch file.
```

My path is set correctly `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16` which is where php.exe is installed.

I have also tried re-installing, and am running version 3.7.24.

Anyone have any tips on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you run "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\phpunit.php" at a Windows command prompt? (phpunit is a php program. I'd expect it to have a php extension under Windows, but I suppose it *could* be something else, like a batch file or a cmd file.)

Comment: I don't have that file installed in my php directory. I only have the bat file.

Comment: What happens if you run "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\phpunit.bat" at a Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPUnit is not set in the PATH global variable. Try installing PHPUnit using PEAR. For win7 use this tutorial: http://designbyjeeba.blogspot.ro/2012/12/easy-way-to-install-pear-and-phpunit-in.html

If PEAR doesn't find any package to install (when trying to install anything using it) clear PEAR's cache:

> pear clear-cache

I dont know the way you installed it, but i did it this way and it works fine for me.
Also i recommend installing DBUnit and PHPUnit selenium. Use the following commands:

> pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium
>
> pear install phpunit/DbUnit

For Linux use the commands given by PHP at the following link:
http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/installation.html